# Учётная запись временно заблокирована с целью дать участнику успокоиться

Tags: обсуждение

[Учётная запись временно заблокирована с целью дать участнику успокоиться. Срок действия блокировки истечёт через 5 дней.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191482/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%A8%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Что это значит и что делает человек чтобы получить такой бан?
Я думаю что дубликат потому-что том описываются последствия бана. А мне нужно узнать про именно этот вид бана. А именно: что это значит и что делает человек чтобы получить такой бан?

Comment: Обычно такая надпись означает, что человек несколько раз подряд [нарушил правило be-nice](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). Короткий срок блокировки - значит нарушил или в первый раз, или не слишком грубо (но достаточно для бана)

Comment: Я думаю что дубликат потому-что том описываются последствия бана. А мне нужно узнать про именно этот вид бана. А именно: что это значит и что делает человек чтобы получить такой бан?

Comment: А при чем тут успокоится?

Comment: Читайте выше: юзер не был мил с юзерами :) Как - вариантов много, точную причину обычно не афишируют, осуждённый может сам рассказать, если будет желание.

Comment: А, вот зачем его нужно поздравлять "с легким паром")